# Which method is more optimal for the base and sorting speed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa

I currently have a list

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("date ASC")
private List<MovieReleaseDateEntity> releaseDates = new ArrayList<>();
```

entities when downloading are sorted by date.

However, as you know, the `List` are not the most suitable for JPA and it is recommended to use `Set`. That's why I have a different idea

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private SortedSet<MovieReleaseDateEntity> releaseDates = new TreeSet<>();
```

and implements `Comparable`

```
public int compareTo(MovieReleaseDateEntity o) {
    return this.date.compareTo(o.date);
}
```

Which way is better? The first with a `List` or the second with `Set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database are designed to execute an `order by` command in an optimized way while the column used in the `order by` is indexed.
So you should favor the ordering by the database if you can tweak the index constraints on your tables.

> However, as you know, the List are not the most suitable for JPA and
>   it is recommended to use Set.

I would rather say that you can not abuse of the `List` mapping in an entity as the number of acceptable is limited for good sense reasons (cardinalities).

You can also see things more simply : if you have few elements, I suppose that using a `Set` is probably an acceptable way in terms of performance.
Otherwise using a `List` with an `order by` done by the database should be probably favored.

In any case, use the structure (`List` or `Set`) that seems the most fine for your use case and then measure the actual performance before changing your design to hope having better performance.

Comment: I have MovieReleaseDateEntity in my application, which stores the premiere dates. Based on the IMDB website https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6644200/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt#releases, where the film has 53 premiere dates. So I would have 53 (MovieReleaseDateEntity) objects on my list. Do you think that there are too many objects to sort into java? My application is similar to IMDB. Or is it better not to sort objects at all and return them unsorted?

Comment: 53 is rather few elements to sort. So in java or in database, it should not change many things. Note that you should also consider the number of entities that you retrieve and that contains this list of `MovieReleaseDateEntity`. If you retrieve 100 of these entities, it may matter. In any case don't do premature optimizations. Use the structure that you need according the functional requirement. A List is easier to manipulate for the client and consumes few memory in comparison to a `TreeSet`. So I would favor this way in first instance and would refactor to `TreeSet` only if unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach (`@OrderBy("date ASC")`) is sorted on database level, and second one is in memory with java implementation. If returned list is big enough in size, it's better to use first approach.

If returned collection is fairly small and you need some complex sort logic (but it's not your case with sorting by specific field), sorting with SortedSet for entity that implements Comparable  might be justified.

Comment: For example, objects of other titles to the movie can have, for example, max. around 25. 25 is it big size?

Comment: as for me 25 is definitely not a big size. but in case size is roughly 1000, it's becomes big :)